# Remove all customers in a certain group

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I have just migrated my M1 site to a newer M2 site, however, this new site will be for wholesale only customers, each of whom are assigned to a different group to reflect their prices.

how can I delete all customers who are currently in the `Retail` group?

I would preferably like to delete everything associated to the customer, such as their addresses and previous orders if possible.

Comment: You can filter all the customers by customer group and then delete it from admin.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

- Login to admin. Then goto Customers -> All Customers.
- Then filter the customer groups by your required customer group.
- Then select Delete from Actions dropdown and Submit

This is the suggested and proper way.

If you want to delete it from database directly need to write mysql query.

Comment: would this also delete their previous orders?

Comment: No. You need to delete the orders manually.